# How to construct bigger std::array from constexpr char*

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

How can I construct a `std::array<char,512>` from a smaller `constexpr const char*` ?

```cpp
#include <array>

strcut A{
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr A(const char (&p)[N]) : a(p) {}
    std::array<char, 512> a;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr const char* s = "asdasd";
    constexpr A a(s);
}
```

The above does not compile. Is it possible somehow? `std::memcpy` does not work as it is not constexpr.
A for loop would work which is stupid...?

Comment: "*A for loop would work which is stupid...?*" Um, why? You're copying a string. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it from `constexpr const char*`, as it looses size information. But you can from a `constexpr char[]`, which you have from the literal, and it is easy enough:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<size_t N, size_t I, size_t... Ix>
constexpr auto make_array(const char (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<Ix...>) {
    return std::array<char, I>{arr[Ix]...};
}

struct A{
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr A(const char (&p)[N]) :
          a(make_array<N, 512>(p, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})) {}

    std::array<char, 512> a;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr decltype(auto) s = "asdasd";
    constexpr A a(s);
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 I would too, as a matter of fact. I was sloppy, and N was already taken :) I would edit.